# Flip 98 fair coins and 1 HH coin and 1 TT coin

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Flip $98$ fair coins and $1 \ HH$ coin and $1 \ TT$ coin. Given that you see an $H$, what is the probability that it was the $HH$ coin.

Applying Bayes Theorem, :

$$P(HH|H) = \frac{P(H|HH) * P(HH)}{P(H)}$$

$P(H|HH) = 1$

$P(HH) = \frac{1}{100}$

$P(H) = \frac{100}{200} = \frac{1}{2}$

So I get $P(HH|H) = \frac{1}{50}$

1) Is this the correct answer?

2) What's wrong with the 'intuitive' answer? I.e. You see $1\ H$, so we only have $99$ possibilities remaining.  Of these $99$, only $1$ of them is $HH => 1/99$

Comment: The reason it's not 1/99 is that there are two sides of the HH coin you could be looking at.

Answer (score 6):

For an "intuitive" answer, there are 100 ways to pick a coin and see heads. Only two of these will result in choosing the HH coin. So the answer is

$$P(HH \mid H) = \dfrac{P(HH \cap H)}{P(H)} = \dfrac{\text{# of ways to pick H and get the HH coin}}{\text{# of ways to pick H}} = \dfrac{2}{100}$$

Comment: @paulkon There are 200 faces, each equally likely to be chosen. One hundred of the faces are Heads. Two of those Heads are assigned to the same coin.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Probability that you see a head given it is a faircoin = P(H)*P(Faircoin) $$= \frac{1}{2}\frac{98}{100}$$

Probability that you see a head given it is a HH coin = P(H)*P(HH coin) $$= 1*\frac{1}{100}$$

Using Bayes' theroem,

Probability that it is HH coin given it is a Head $$\frac{1*\frac{1}{100}}{\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{98}{100}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{50}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Bayes' theorem is obviously the correct way to answer the question, but I think a good / valid layman's term answer is:

- There are $200$ faces, and $100$ of those are heads ($98$ from the fair coins, $2$ from the $HH$ coin);
- If I'm seeing a heads, it means I saw one of the $100$ faces that could be heads;
- Since $2$ of those $100$ heads faces are provided by the $HH$ coin, if I'm seeing heads, $2/100$ or $1/50$ is the probability that I'm seeing a face of the $HH$ coin.